# Snowflake java UDF AES_256/GCM/NoPadding not available

Tags: java, encryption, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have external encrypt function written in Groovy and try to write the decrypt UDF in Snowflake using Java. I'm getting the error. java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting "AES_256/GCM/NoPadding" at java. Base/javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:565) at function_handler_0//utility.decrypt(InlineCode.java:32)

Here is the java function:

```
private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 256;
private static final int ITERATION_COUNT = 10000; //65536;
private static final byte[] iv = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
// private static GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);

public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secretKey, String salt) {

    try {

        GCMParameterSpec parameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv);
        byte[] encryptedData = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt);

        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), 65536, 256);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");
   
        //cipher creation and decryption
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES_256/GCM/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, parameterSpec);
        byte[] decryptedText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
        return new String(decryptedText, "UTF-8");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle the exception properly
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The decrypt function is working fine outside of Snowflake.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [The Java name for AES/GCM is `AES/GCM/NoPadding`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html)

Comment: Is this an issue with the java unlimited strength encryption? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E60058_01/PDF/8.0.6.x/8.0.6.0.0/AG_HTML/Enabling_Unlimited_Cryptographic_Policy_for_Java.htm which version of java is snowflake running?

Comment: @matt JDK() 11.0.14.1

Comment: @AndrewHenle but it works outside of snowflake just fine.

Comment: @LeoG Just because some Java implementations accept cryptographic algorithms outside the [Java standards](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) doesn't mean every implementation will.  Nevermind the "256" is redundant in `AES_256` anyway as the number of algorithm bits is specified by the size of the key.  It's actually worse than redundant - now you need more code to handle both AES-128 and AES-256.  If you just use the Java-standard `AES/GCM/NoPadding` only one version of code can handle all key sizes...

Comment: @AndrewHenle So what you are saying that because I use 256 in PBEKeySpec then it does not matter. So I tried but now I get javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Error finalising cipher data: mac check in GCM failed
Also it seem there is a bouncycatle reference at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ClassUtil.throwBadTagException(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BaseCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)

Comment: @LeoG Either your key is wrong, your IV is wrong, your ciphertext is wrong, or your AEAD tag data is wrong.  You haven't provided any information on how your ciphertext is created, or how the ciphertext, key, iv, and tag are passed from your encryption process to the decryption code you've posted.